# YouTube API v3 Java authorization

Tags: java, youtube-api, credentials, youtube-data-api

I'm using the YouTube Data API (Java) to upload videos to my YouTube channel.
I've tested it on my Windows PC and succeeded.
But the authorization in the sample makes a Credential instance by opening a browser window to signin to Google.
This is fine on my Windows PC, but I'm trying to get this code to work on a remote linux machine that I only have SSH access to.

I've searched stackoverflow for similar questions, and found the exact same question. But as that question doesn't have the specific tags that Google engineers require, I'm posting it as a new question.

[Youtube API V3 Java Any possible without invoking browser to upload video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410410/youtube-api-v3-java-any-possible-without-invoking-browser-to-upload-video)

If you have any idea you can help, I'd be really grateful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked for ways to accomplish this and found it.
I followed the instructions at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

You need a new OAuth Client ID and set it up as an "Service account" in the Developers Console - APIs & auth - Credentials, and then download the P12 key.

You also need to change the Permissions of the service account to "Is owner" from the Developers Console.

Then change the code

```
Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "uploadvideo");
```

to

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
.setTransport(httpTransport)
.setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
.setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("MyProject.p12"))
.setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(SQLAdminScopes.SQLSERVICE_ADMIN))
.setServiceAccountUser("user@example.com")
.build();
```

as specified in the URL above. emailAddress is the email address from the service account, the P12 filename must be changed, Collections.~~~ should be changed to scopes (the premade one in the original example), finally the serviceAccountUser should be your original Gmail ID.

I succeeded with the above method, hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Howard - how do I set the service-account to "Is owner"? I can only give it Edit permissions, where my user-account is an owner. When I try to "setServiceAccountUser" I get a "401 Unauthorized".

Comment: You can change it the Developers Console (http://console.developers.google.com/project), select your project, click Permissions in the left frame.
In the right frame, you should see accounts, and you can set them to "Is owner".
Oh, in the setServiceAccountUser, I put my original Gmail account (***@gmail.com).

Comment: I can add a user account as an owner, not the service-account. But I figured out around my issue.

Comment: How did you do it? What was the problem?

Comment: @HowardYang, can you help me ? erjobertolazo@gmail.com , send me a email plis i need help

Answer (score 0):

You could use SSH as a proxy and then use a local browser to use that proxy.

ssh -ND 8080 user@server.example.com
That sets a SOCKS proxy. Just edit your browser's proxy settings to IP: localhost Port: 8080 and your traffic is going out over SSH.

Just remember that all your browser's traffic is going through the proxy until you disable it so don't do anything against network policy while you're logged in. I might suggest using a private instance of Chrome, for example.

Note: This probably won't work for domain lookups so you'll need the local (to the SSH host) IP of the router.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea you could do that. But as I needed to automate things I needed another solution and I found one. It involves server-to-server OAuth 2.0. I'll make my own answer. Thanks!