# o.auth2 ERROR : Trying to fetch an Analytics report with Youtube API

Tags: java, youtube-api

I am currently working on a Java app to calculate a certain index. I need to feed it data from Youtube such as views, average minute watched, geography, etc. from a channel which I am now set as  "owner".

I am trying to connect the app using Youtube Analytics API but get this error every time :

> com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401
>   Unauthorized

The code I am using is from google developer GitHub so I assume the error is not in the code.

I went back to the online console to try my credentials, and they don't work. I have generated and deleted so many Keys and clients but nothing seems to work. Note that I am able to trigger requests like search which don't require authentification. So the problem is precisely in the auth, but I can't see what it is.

Thanks!

Comment: please provide example code of what you are using to call.

Comment: I got all samples from here : https://github.com/youtube/api-samples
- to be imported as json project -

Comment: well i mean like this post should have some code in it. so we know more what you are trying to do . [you may want to look here about how to create Google creds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097266/youtube-api-v3-java-authorization)